# element.isDisplayed() method is returning false though locator is correct and getting highlighted on browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using the `element.isDisplayed()` method where element is getting correctly highlighted on browser but while running script it returning `false`.
If I do other operation like `element.isSelected()` and `element.isEnabled()`, then I am getting correct value but in case of `element.isDisplayed()`, I am always getting return value as `false`.

I am assuming its because of embedded tag (INPUT is completely inside SPAN). So how can we make `isDisplayed()` return `true` in this case? I am using below CSS locator and as per attached screenshot its highlighted so the locator is absolutely correct `input[data-testid*='checkbox'][id*='date-range']`

HTML:

```
<span class="sc-gfbwvm fsIrkY">
  <input id="date-range-switcher-id-internal" data-testid="ds-checkbox" aria-labelledby="date-range-switcher-id-internal_label date-range-switcher-id-internal_block_label" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" name="Date range" label="Date Range" type="checkbox" class="sc-cmUMNf ekCFch DSCheckbox-input">
  ::after ==$0
</span>
```

I tried other method on same element like `element.isSelected()` and `element.isEnabled()` and I am getting correct return value accordingly.

Comment: You're provided an ID on that element, why not just use it as is? `By.id("date-range-switcher-id-internal")`? My guess is that you've either got more than on element on the page that is matching or you need to add a wait.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Comment: thanks Jeff for responding..I have tried with By.id("date-range-switcher-id-internal") but still its not working. There is no issue of wait also because while debugging also it is returning false only

Answer (score 0):

Some elements take some time to load or display on the web page so you need to try explicitly wait for finding the element and then use `element.isDisplayed()` method

Example in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=10)
elem=wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='tab-space']")))
print(elem.is_enabled())
print(elem.is_displayed())
```

The example I have given is in Python code, you can try it in your own language.

Comment: As I already mentioned there is no issue with wait as while debugging also its getting failed